# Cannot get Nexus 9000v to respond on more than one port in ESXi 6.7

Tags: virtualization, cisco, esxi

I have installed 5 different versions (7.0.3(I6).2 through 9.2.4) of NXOS on ESXi 6.7. The management port is configurable. And sometimes I can get one additional Layer 3 port to respond. But I can't seem to get any other ports to respond, by which I mean I configure the port for L3 (no switchport) and assign an IP address and "no shut" the port.

I have used Ansible automation to configure, test and then disable all 128 ports with no luck. I have tried all possible permutations of configuration options on the ESXi vSwitch.

There are hundreds if not thousands of web sites on "how to set up 9000v with ESXi" but they all basically stop once the device is reachable using SSH and most are for ESXi 6.5. I have not seen one that specified a 6.7 setup.

There just aren't that many options for configuration, and I am guessing that there MUST be something I am overlooking in the 9000v feature set, or within ESXi.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Turn off spanning tree on the Nexus port.

I ran tcpdump on a unix box sharing a vSwitch and saw layer 2 traffic, meaning that the NXOS was actually transmitting traffic through the vSwitch and it was reaching the unix box. I also saw that the traffic was spanning tree info, which led me to looking at the port status and then eventually shutting off spanning tree at the port level. Then all the Layer 3 ports responded as expected.